# App crashes before viewController loads after segue call

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller, mkmapview

I have a splitViewController with a masterView that has four buttons that segue to four different views. One of my views is a mapView which is populated with annotations based on user entered location data. A user enters an address which is stored in core data, and the mapView takes the lat and long of the addresses entered and populates the map.

The problem that I am getting is- when I segue to the map and then segue to another view before the annotations are plotted on the map, my app crashes and the NSEnabledZombie error says- " [viewController respondsToSelector: ] : message sent to deallocated instance." If I allow the annotations to load, it runs fine and doesn't crash. I placed a sleep function in in the viewDidAppear for now so that annotations have time to load when you segue to it.

Should I place the loading code in a different thread or is there a better way to do this other than having a sleep function?

here is the method for the annotations:

```
-(void)showAddresses {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchR = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"theAddrs" inManagedObjectContext:self.manageCont];
    [fetchR setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *theLoc = [self.manageCont executeFetchRequest:fetchR error:&error];

        NSError *saveError = nil;
        [self.manageCont save:&saveError];
}
```

And here I am calling it in viewDidAppear:

```
   -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[self showAddresses];
}
```

Comment: Could you paste a code snippet?

Comment: I have edited the post with code.

Comment: What message is being sent and to which deallocated object?  (It sounds as if something may have a delegate pointer that should be cleared.)

Comment: It look likes it's losing reference to core data.

Comment: Where is your `self.manageCont` set? And I don't think you need the last two lines as you are only reading from the db.

Comment: You're right I don't need the last two lines. The self.manageCont is passed from another view controller.

Comment: I am setting the map view delegate equal to itself and using viewForAnnotation to create custom annotations. I have  self.mapView.delegate=self in viewDidLoad. If I comment out the self.mapView.delegate=self it runs without crashing on segue but it takes out my custom annotations and uses the (default) pins. Can I call the delegate somewhere else in code so that it runs without errors and still displays my custom annotations?